# How can reordering the linked libraries fix multiple definitions error?

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, multiple-definition-error

I faced a situation where different order of linking [librdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/src/lz4.h) and the [Pulsar C++ client](https://github.com/apache/pulsar/blob/master/pulsar-client-cpp/lib/lz4/lz4.h) does matter, because both of them include their version of LZ4 compression. The linking fails because of multiple definitions of LZ4 functions (both librdkafka and Pulsar have the same names for those functions). I checked the static libraries, but I couldn't find anything suspicious, why it works in one order and doesn't in the another. Because it is hard to provide a minimal working example with those big libraries, I tried to reproduce the same situation, and I was able to do so. I created a [small project](https://github.com/antaljanosbenjamin/multiple-definition) where the linking order matters.

libA.hpp:

```
#pragma once

void NotClashingFunctionA();
void ClashingFunction();
```

libA.cpp:

```
#include "libB.hpp"

#include <iostream>

void NotClashingFunctionA() {
    std::cout << "Not clashing function A\n";
}

void ClashingFunction() {
    std::cout << "Clashing function A\n";
}
```

libB.hpp:

```
#pragma once

void NotClashingFunctionB();
```

libB.cpp:

```
#include "libB.hpp"

#include <iostream>

void NotClashingFunctionB() {
    std::cout << "Not clashing function B\n";
}
```

libBSub.hpp:

```
#pragma once

void ClashingFunction();
```

libBSub.cpp:

```
#include "libBSub.hpp"

#include <iostream>

void ClashingFunction() {
    std::cout << "Clashing function B\n";
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "libA.hpp"
#include "libB.hpp"
#include "libBSub.hpp"

int main() {
    NotClashingFunctionA();
    NotClashingFunctionB();
    ClashingFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(clashing)

add_library(A STATIC libA.cpp)

add_library(B STATIC libB.cpp libBSub.cpp)

add_executable(working main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(working A B)

add_executable(failing main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(failing B A)
```

From the logs I can clearly see that `working` just links fine:

```
clang++ -g -rdynamic CMakeFiles/working.dir/main.cpp.o -o working  libA.a libB.a 
make[3]: Leaving directory 'build'
[100%] Built target working
```

But `failing` fails to link:

```
clang++ -g -rdynamic CMakeFiles/failing.dir/main.cpp.o -o failing  libB.a libA.a 
ld: libA.a(libA.cpp.o): in function `ClashingFunction()':
libA.cpp:9: multiple definition of `ClashingFunction()'; libB.a(libBSub.cpp.o):libBSub.cpp:5: first defined here
clang-12: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I removed the common prefixes to make the logs more readable.

As you can see the only difference between the two is the linking order `A` and `B`. I don't know why it works in `A B` order, and not `B A` order.

If you cannot explain it in details, helping keywords are also very appreciated, because I have absolutely no idea why it is happening.

Comment: The code breaks the One-Definition-Rule (ODR) - no diagnostic required - and is an example of Undefined Behaviour - see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition  specifically _"One and only one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used is required to appear in the entire program ...The compiler is not required to diagnose this violation, but the behavior of the program that violates it is undefined...."_

Comment: Thanks! To be honest I haven't faced a situation where the violation of ODR doesn't ended up in a linker error, therefore I was thinking that it might be actually valid because of some edge cases. Now I checked, and GCC behaves in the same way as Clang, and this makes me curious. I know it is still UB, but it seems both Clang and GCC implemented this in the same way. But thats a different topic!

Comment: since you static library is copied into you program it will clash in linking so I rppose you add some namespace to your libraries .

Comment: Yes, it was clear. The question was about why it is working in one order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand *why*, read this (earlier) [post](https://web.archive.org/web/20180627210132/http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html) or [this](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking) (nicer) one.

To make a concrete example:

- suppose `main.o` defines `main()`, `fn()`, and references `a()` and `b()`.
- `libA.a` contains `a.o` which defines `a()`
- `libB.a` contains `b.o` which defines `b()`, *and* also `a1.o` which defines `a()` and `fn()`.

Now, if you link with `gcc main.o -lA -lB`, the link will succeed (`a.o` from `libA.a` and `b.o` from `libB.a` will be selected into the link, and no symbol conflicts will arise. Notably, `a1.o` from `libB.a` will *not* be selected into the link).

But if you link with `gcc main.o -lB -lA`, then `fn()` will be *multiply defined* (because both `a1.o` and `b.o` from `libB.a` will be selected into the link, but the definition of `fn()` in `a1.o` will be in conflict with the definition of `fn()` in `main.o`).

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation and links, I really think I understood the whole situation based on your answer!